# Tensorflow ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([])

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use batch to read image from file folder.But after decode,that might be some problems when I use `tf.train.batch`. Here is the code.

```
def get_batch(image, label, batch_size, capacity):

image = tf.cast(image, tf.string)
label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)

input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image, label])

label = input_queue[1]
image_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)
image = tf.image.per_image_whitening(image) 

image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label],
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            num_threads = 8, 
                                            capacity = capacity)

label_batch = tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])
image_batch = tf.cast(image_batch, tf.float32)

return image_batch, label_batch
```

And the error said I haven't define some tensorshapes. I don't know how to do.Maybe I did't use decode in a proper way.Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input_data.py", line 118, in <module>
    image_batch, label_batch = get_batch(image_list, label_list, BATCH_SIZE, CAPACITY)
  File "input_data.py", line 90, in get_batch
    capacity = capacity)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 538, in batch
    capacity=capacity, dtypes=types, shapes=shapes, shared_name=shared_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 453, in __init__
    shapes = _as_shape_list(shapes, dtypes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 71, in _as_shape_list
    raise ValueError("All shapes must be fully defined: %s" % shapes)
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the data you want to batch must have pre-defined shape, in you case, tensor `image` doesn't, you need to specify the shape with `image.set_shape` or `tf.image.resize_images`